# Show when the suggested edits has been suggested, in the statistics for the suggested edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

The page reporting the statistics for the suggested edits always says "just now" for the pending edits.

[image: screenshot]

Following [the link for the first pending edit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1796) (the link is for 10k users on Drupal Answers), I notice the edit has been suggested more than 30 minutes ago.

[image: screenshot]

If then I look at [the statistics for the week](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tools/suggested-edits?filter=week&tab=all) (the link is for 10k users on Drupal Answers), I notice the same is done for edits suggested more than two days ago.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

The statistics should shown when the suggested edit has been suggested, not "just now." 
As alternative, for the pending edits the page should not show any timestamp, as always showing "just now" doesn't give any useful information; at worst, it gives wrong information.

Comment: I guess technically it's correct since they are still pending, but showing the time it was submitted would be more helpful here.